# VSTO Outlook: set custom tooltips on task pane buttons

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, customtaskpane

I have been trying to set custom tooltips for custom task pane buttons, that is, close button and down-arrow button. I have seen they already have a tooltip set by default but I would like to change it to show a custom text. Is that possible? or even is it also possible to change the tooltip style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office/Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. There is no trivial way to specify a tooltip for these controls. The [CustomTaskPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane?view=vsto-2017) interface doesn't provide any property or method for that.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it. I supposed it ;)